# What's the purpose of mysql database(schema) in installed MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

In [the MySQL's manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/), it mentions database information_schema and database performance_schema, they both have a dedicated chapters; but it seems it doesn't mention much about the database mysql. What's purpose of this database? What kind of information does it have? Is there an official documentation to explain about it?

Answer (score 1):

These databases manage things like the location of the stored procedures you write and the database functions you write. Additionally, your permissions information is stored there. MySQL uses these DBs to store info about itself and your other databases. Its worth looking through these DBs to gain an even better understanding of what they are up to, but I assure you they are important.

Answer (score 0):

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is not a database, but set of read-only views or system mappings that provide an ability to enumerate information about database in vendor-agnostic format as specified by ANSI SQL92 standard.

Each database vendor has own native mechanism to find information like list of tables, columns, types, indexes, etc. For example, for MySQL it is `SHOW TABLES`, for PostgreSQL it is `psql \d`, etc. Unfortunately, for each database type native method to get this info is different.

To solve this problem, all known database vendors - MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL, Oracle, etc, also implement support for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, such that client software can find list of tables, list of columns, column types and widths and other similar information using exactly the same interface.

Regarding `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA` - it is MySQL extension to provide a look into server performance operation and tuning, and is not part of any standard. Other vendors may provide similar tools, but they are all vendor specific.